# Count SQL Query not returning expected value

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

I'm trying to have a method return a count statement.

```
    public int getSettingsCount(string UserId, string Setting)
    {
        int LastSetting;
        //var user = new SqlDataLayer();
        using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(this.DBPath))
        {
            {
                List<int> _setting = db.Query<int>("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM QTabSettings WHERE UserId = 1058 AND Setting = 'ServerDropdown' GROUP BY UserId;");
                LastSetting = Convert.ToInt32(_setting.SingleOrDefault());
            }
            return LastSetting;
        }
    }
```

When I execute the query it returns the correct value (6). However I am getting  the value (0) from my above query.

How can I get the method to return the count as an int?

Comment: What do you expect `LIMIT 1` to accomplish?

Comment: Good point, I removed it.

Comment: And why do you `ORDER BY TimeStamp`? This query will return a single row anyway.

Comment: Code seems to be correct, but I would try to change the `List<int>` in a `List<long>` and making the appropriate changes everywhere. Just to try a crazy thought.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `LIMIT 1` and still using `List<int>` that's strange and unnecessary. Also since it's `count(*)` there is no need of `LIMIT 1` since the result would be a scalar data. Should change it to

```
int _setting = db.Query<int>("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM QTabSettings WHERE UserId = 1058 AND Setting = 'ServerDropdown';");
LastSetting = _setting;
```

Comment: Plus the `Group By` being also unnecessary in his query as we filter on a unique user.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question properly I think this is what you want:

```
LastSetting = _setting.FirstOrDefault();
```

or:

```
LastSetting = _setting[0];
```

Comment: This returns 1, because there is only one value in the list. I need access to that actual value.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are using a List, but try doing LastSetting = _setting.FirstOrDefault();

Comment: Because if I don't there is a compiling error saying that you cant convert an int into a list implicitly.

Comment: `_setting.count()` will return the count property of the list and not the DB count value. Does it not?

Comment: @Rahul Yes that is correct - I had misunderstood the question.